# How to deal with variables which have large amount of NAs

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

currently I got three datasets: DS-A, DS-B and DS-C. Basically I hope to use these data to find out some typical/potential customers/targets for a certain group to make business plan with the help of some kinds of machine learning methods.

Take DS-A as **an example**:

```
tun_account <- read.csv("./Accounts.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

dim(tun_account)
[1] 233273    258

tun_account[, which(apply(tun_account, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x) > 0.7))] %>% ncol()
[1] 73

tun_account[, which(apply(tun_account, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x) > 0.9))] %>% ncol()
[1] 57
```

As shown above, DS-A is a 233273x258 dataset, and among its 258 variables, there are 73 variables which have the number of NAs outnumbered a certain threshold (here are 0.7 and 0.9, but it could be changed).

I understand that usually, we could impute NAs by applying lots of fancy methods like KNN, means, and so on. However, my question is, in my current context, **do I need to impute these variables (will it be necessary to do that?) or just drop them (I am not sure whether these variables they are important or not)**

Comment: There are several questions on this general topic, such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262925/is-there-a-serious-problem-with-dropping-observations-with-missing-values-when-c/263033#263033).

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly try imputing them, but if a variable is missing most of the time, let alone 90% of the time, it's unlikely to be useful for anything. Imputation works best when a small minority of cases are missing.

Comment: I would run the variable through a random forest tool (Boruta) to figure out if the non-NA is informative.  Imputing something like this, instead of truncating it, can lead to some pathological model behaviors when you fit on the imputed data.

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to impute these variables (will it be necessary to do that?) or just drop them (I am not sure whether these variables they are important or not)

It depends which methods to apply.

For tree method, they are immune to missing value, like EngrStudent have said.

For others, maybe you can imputed the missing value, or encoding this numerical variable to category variables (treat missing value as a factor level too)